# what happen to a sequence of matrix if their 2-norm tends to 0

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to show that if a sequence of matrices $A_i$ with the 2-norm tending to $0$ then the sequence tends to the zero matrix. Is this true?

Here the norm of a matrix $A$ is defined by $\sup_x||Ax||_2$ where $||x||=1$.

Comment: I made a mistake for the definition of the norm...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the min over all $x$ is certainly no larger than the result of simply picking $x = e_1$, in which case if $A_i = \pmatrix{a_i & b_i \\ c_i & d_i}$, then $A_ix$ is $\pmatrix{a_i\\c_i}$, so $\| A_ix \| = \sqrt{a_i^2 + c_i^2} \le \sqrt{a_i^2} = |a_i|$. If you know that this tends to zero, what's it tell you about the upper-left entry of the limit of the $A_i$?

Comment: I don't understand how $\sqrt{a_i^2+c_i^2} \leq \sqrt{a_i^2}$?

Comment: Ok i understand now!